# Using external links inside django admin to create or update

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I am using a [redactor wysiwyg editor](https://imperavi.com/redactor/) to write my content. The page has only the wysiwyg editor and a save button.

html:

```
<div id="editor-wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="editor-title" {%if blog %} value="{{blog.title}}" {% else %} placeholder="Your title" {% endif %}>
    <textarea id="editor-redactor" name="content">
        {% if blog %}
            {{ blog.body }}
        {% else %}
            <p>Enter you body in here...</p>
        {% endif %}
    </textarea>
    <button id="save-btn"><a href="/save-blog/">Save</a> </button>
</div>
```

And in the urls.py I have added the url to go to that page.

```
url(r'^add-update-blog/$', views.add_update_blog),
url(r'^add-update-blog/save/(?P<blog_id>\d+)$', views.add_update_blog),
```

views.py:

```
def add_update_blog(request):
    return render(request, 'editor.html')

def add_update_blog_save(request, blog_id):
    blog = Blog.objects.get(id=blog_id)
    return render(request, 'editor.html', {
        blog: blog
    })
```

Now, in the django-admin panel there may be list of already written contents:

- If I click on add, I want to go to the editor page.
- If I click on any of the already written content object, I want to get that object and load it in the editor page.

Right now it displays the list and when I click add or on the content it is displayed inside the admin panel only. How do I achieve what I want? Your help and guidance is really very much appericated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to *hijack* the admin urls, and use your own views for those urls, i.e., the admin url won't change, but your editor page views will be called instead of the default admin views. ([Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls), [Source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L545))

```
from .views import add_update_blog, add_update_blog_save

class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(BlogAdmin, self).get_urls()
        new_urls = [
             url(r'^add/$', add_update_blog),
             url(r'^(?P<blog_id>\d+)/change/$', add_update_blog_save),
        ]
        return new_urls + urls    # new_urls have to be first
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it is possible that your problems are caused by a missing (or extra) trailing slash on the end of your urls. Your `add-update-blog` url requires a trailing slash, while the `save` url will not match if there is a trailing slash. You can use the regular-expression syntax `/?` to make the slash optional, as in my example below. Notably, the Django admin urls *only match when there is trailing slash*.

As jatinderjit mentioned, "hijacking" the admin urls is necessary. However, 
this can be done in simple way within `urls.py`. By including a url that would match an admin url *before* we include the admin urls we can guarantee the redirect to our custom view will be matched first. This is easy to do with the [RedirectView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview) and [named url patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns), which will pass your `blog_id` parameter to the view you have already written.

```python
''' Snippet of urls.py'''
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
    # Put this before the admin include so that it is found first.
    # Don't forget to replace 'app-label' and 'blog' with the
    # appropriate names, if different.
    url(r'^admin/app-label/blog/(?P<blog_id>\d+)/?$',
        RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='edit_blog',
                             permanent=False)),
    # The actual admin urls.
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    # The urls to redirect to. Note that naming them makes
    # redirecting much easier.
    url(r'^add-update-blog/?$',
        views.add_update_blog,
        name='add_blog'),
    url(r'^add-update-blog/save/(?P<blog_id>\d+)/?$',
        views.add_update_blog,
        name='edit_blog'),
    # All your other urls...
]
```